# jquery filter does not pick up data attribute in url hashing

Tags: jquery, filter, fragment, custom-data-attribute, jquery-1.9

I tested the url that contains hash/ fragment and it works 'theoretically' below, but when I test the codes below on browser that has an url with fragemnt, then I get nothing from `data`,

for instance, this is the url on my browser,

```
http://localhost/xxx/cms/#/news/manage?set=1&page=1
```

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    base_url = 'http://localhost/xxx/';
    var fragment = location.hash; // for instance - '#/news/manage?set=1&page=1';

    var data = $(".button").filter("[href*='" + base_url + 'cms/' + fragment + "']").data('query');
    alert(data);
});
```

html,

```
<ul class="pagination">

    <li><a href="http://localhost/xxx/cms/#/news/manage?set=1&page=1" class="button" data-query="page.php?method=list&system_id=57&set=1&page=1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/xxx/cms/#/news/manage?set=1&page=2" class="button" data-query="page.php?method=list&system_id=57&set=1&page=2">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

so for the example above, I should get this as my `data`,

```
page.php?method=list&system_id=57&set=1&page=1
```

how come I get `null` whenever I refresh the url with fragment on my browser?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(fragment)` to confirm that the fragment is what you expect?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dyx6S/

Comment: yes it works in that way. but you get nothing if the # string is coming from your browser url bar...

Comment: Then obviously the fragment isn't what you expect, despite your confirmation.

Comment: sorry, it works now. i think there are some bugs in my main codes. thanks for the help.